# System thread exception not handled (ndis.sys) 0xc1900101 0x40017 upgrading to Win 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, bsod, windows-update

I want to upgrade a PC from Win7 to Win10 keeping file and apps because there is some software that I cannot reconfigure so I have to avoid the clean install.

I installed it with a pendrive made with the media-creation tool.

The problem starts after the driver installation step and the second boot, it ran in BSOD with error:

```
System thread exception not handled (ndis.sys)
```

Then after 3 reboot attempts with the same BSOD it restores Win7 and shows the update error with these codes:

```
0xc1900101 0x40017
```

[image: Errore after reboot]

I started to read something about win10 update failures and looking for these error codes, therefore I tried something:

1. Update BIOS and all drivers
2. Unplug all external peripheral except of mouse and keyboard
3. Remove all add-in cards (example graphic card, I used only motherboard vga card)
4. Uninstall all devices and its software (graphic card switching to VGA resolution and base card, network adapter, usb3 controller)
5. Disable all integrated peripheral from BIOS setup (com port, network adapter, graphics accelerator, all other non-essential features)
6. Switch Windows 7 to driver test mode to avoid driver signature problem

With each one of these tests I had the same BSOD problem.
Can I do something else?

Comment: You can use windbg to verify which device driver is causing this problem.  Simplest solution of course is to manually configure your system not to load the problem device driver.  This will allow you to perform the upgrade to Windows 10 then allowing you to install Windows 10 compatible drivers for said device.

Comment: How can I manually configure my system and do not load driver?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft KB page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107983) this errors means a faulty driver:

> This error occurs when the Windows 10 upgrade fails after the second
>   system restart. They’re likely caused by faulty drivers or software.
>   The following drivers and software are known to cause these errors:
>
> **SteelSeries mouse and keyboard software**. The SteelSeries Engine is currently not supported on Windows 8.1. This causes issues
>   when you try to upgrade to Windows 10. For more information, see the
>   SteelSeries FAQ.
>   **NVIDIA video card software**. Make sure that you have the latest video driver installed.
>   **ESET antivirus and security-related products**. See the ESET knowledge base to learn how to safely upgrade to Windows 10 with ESET
>   products installed.
>   **Trusteer Rapport** credit-card fraud-protection software. Trusteer recommends that you install the available Windows 8.1 updates
>   before you upgrade to Windows 10.
>       McAfee antivirus and security-related products. McAfee AntiVirus 8.8 Patch 3 is confirmed to be incompatible with Windows 10.
>
> **Resolution 1**
>   Do a clean boot into Windows, and then upgrade to Windows 10.
>
> **Resolution 2**
>   Run Setup.exe for Windows 10 together with the /DynamicUpdate parameter. This parameter lets the Windows 10 Setup program check for
>   available driver updates during the setup process.

`ndis.sys` is related to network drivers, so update all network drivers and all related software (Av suite)

Comment: really ndis is related network and not to video card? I already tried to update all available drivers and also to uninstall them and moreover I tried to disable network adapter by BIOS option, but it doesn't work... What do you mean for Av suite?

Comment: ndis stands for Network Driver Interface Specification, so network related. AV = **A**nti**V**irus

Comment: any update? have you tried to update all network drivers and all network related software?

Comment: yes, but I had no luck. As I said I also tried to disble the network adapter from BIOS settings, but I did not solved.

Comment: remove other network related software. Also look if you have the file **setupmem.dmp** in the C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Source\Panther folder. if yes, share this dmp, maybe I see details in the debugger

Comment: I did not find this dump file.

Comment: have you enabled the option to show hidden files?

Comment: Yes, I renounce the update...

Comment: install Win10 in a second partition and activate it before 29th with the Win7 key and now the activation servers store that your hardware is allowed to use Win10. Try to update later when the 1607 update is out on 2nd August

Comment: can you upgrade to version 1607? or do you still get the same error?